# BabyNames how to return only one line

Tags: java, line, return

I have an assignment where the user is asked for baby name using a scanner. Then it reads through files names.txt and meanings.txt and returns the popularity of the name for each decade ranging from 1890 - 2010 then it prints out the meaning. Some names have multiple meanings and some are used in both genders. The assignment states to print only the first line where the name is found. I am having trouble only returning the first line in which the name is found. PLEASE HELP ME!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class BabyNames4 {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

      printIntro();

      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Name: ");
      String searchWord = console.next();

      Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));
      String dataLine = find(searchWord, fileScan);
      if (dataLine.length() > 0) {

         while (dataLine.length() > 0) {
            printName(dataLine);
            dataLine = find(searchWord, fileScan);
         }
      }

      Scanner fileScan2 = new Scanner(new File("meanings.txt"));
      String dataLine2 = find(searchWord, fileScan2);
      if (dataLine2.length() > 0) {

         while (dataLine2.length() > 0) {
            printMeaning(dataLine2);
            dataLine2 = find(searchWord, fileScan2);
         }
      }
   }

   public static void printIntro() {   
      System.out.println("This program allows you to search through the");
         System.out.println("dada from the Social Security Administration");
         System.out.println("to see how popular a particular name has been");
         System.out.println("since 1890");
         System.out.println();         
   }

   public static String find(String searchWord, Scanner fileScan) {
      while (fileScan.hasNextLine()) {
         String dataLine = fileScan.nextLine();
         String dataLineLC = dataLine.toLowerCase();

         if (dataLineLC.contains(searchWord.toLowerCase())) {
            return dataLine;
         //} else {              runs a continuous loop                       
            //System.out.println(search" not found.");   
         }
      }
      return "";    
   }

   public static void printName(String dataLine) {
      Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(dataLine);

      String name = lineScan.next();                        
      String gender = lineScan.next();
      String rank = "";
      while (lineScan.hasNext()) {
         rank += lineScan.next() + " "; 
      }                                        
      System.out.println(name + (" ") + gender + (" ") + rank);
   }

   public static void printMeaning(String dataLine2) {
      Scanner lineScan2 = new Scanner(dataLine2);

      String name2 = lineScan2.next();                        
      String gender2 = lineScan2.next();
      String language = lineScan2.next();
      String meaning = "";
      while (lineScan2.hasNext()) {
         meaning += lineScan2.next() + " "; 
      }
      System.out.println(name2 + (" ") + gender2 + (" ") + language + (" ") + meaning);      
   } 
}
```

Comment: `break` out of the loops after you print

Answer (score 2):

It looks like sushain hit it with his comment.
The loop:

```
while (dataLine2.length() > 0) {
        printMeaning(dataLine2);
        dataLine2 = find(searchWord, fileScan2);
    }
```

could be changed to:

```
while (dataLine2.length() > 0) {
    printMeaning(dataLine2);
    break;
}
```

This way you do not find the second definition and do not print it.

Answer (score 1):

In this loop, you don't need to find the next line, correct?

```
if (dataLine.length() > 0) {

     while (dataLine.length() > 0) {
        printName(dataLine);
        dataLine = find(searchWord, fileScan);  // remove this line
     }
}
```

If you remove the next find to dataLine and remove the `while` blocks in both instances where you search the file, you won't need a break, and you'll only end up printing one instance.

Do this:

```
String dataLine = find(searchWord, fileScan);
if (dataLine.length() > 0) {
    printName(dataLine);
}
```